# Blazor Server-App: Bind code behind to multiple Razor-components

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to make a mobile desgin for my already existing blazor-server application
I currently have my .razor files and the code behind in .razor.cs files.

**What i want to do now is, to use 2 Front ends refering to the same Backend.**

For Example

```
FooDesktop.razor -> Foo.razor.cs 
FooMobile.razor -> Foo.razor.cs
```

Is this possible? If no what are my alternatives.

Comment: I would look into creating a DI service that you can `@inject IMyFooService service` and use that as a backend for multiple frontends. You could also move some of the front-end code to Components and do `@if (IsMobile) { <MobileFrontend/> } else { <DesktopFrontend/>}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes that would be a possible solution (imo not a good one). I found an even better solution I will post it tomorrow cheers.

Comment: That is indeed a good, and correct solution.  If you're looking to try something other than the suggestion from @RobinGM you may find yourself in a heap of technical debt.

Comment: `FooDesktop : @inherits Foo` `FooMobile: @inherits Foo`

Comment: @AdamVincent can you see any technical debt in the solution i posted?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution I came up with goes like:

1. Foo.razor.cs goes into a seperate class like FooComponent.cs
2. FooMobile.razor and FooDesktop.razor now inherits this base class
3. U can you all functionality of the base type inside your razor component